# Kernel patching in stm32mp1 yocto

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, yocto, openembedded

I am learning how to add a kernel patch in yocto. My yocto kernel meta-layer is based on
linux-stm32mp_5.10.bb from meta-st-stm32mp. First thing i do is to create a patch from

```
/home/kj/stm32Yoctominimal/build-mp1/tmp/work-shared/stm32mp1/kernel-source
```

I modified `init/main.c` and create a patch: `0001-Stargazer-OS-Kernel-Enablement.patch`

I created a meta-layer, in my layer. My recipe kernel has the following structure:

```
── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── linux-stm32mp
        │   ├── 5.10
        │   │   └── 5.10.61
        │   │       └── 0001-Stargazer-OS-Kernel-Enablement.patch
        │   ├── defconfig
        │   └── kj.cfg
        └── linux-stm32mp_5.10.bbappend
```

In the bbappend file of my layer I has the following content

```
kj@kj-Aspire-V3-471G:~/stm32Yoctominimal/meta-kjlau$ cat recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stm32mp_5.10.bbappend

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://kj.cfg \
            file://${LINUX_VERSION}/${LINUX_VERSION}.${LINUX_SUBVERSION}/0001-Stargazer-OS-Kernel-Enablement.patch"

#Appply default kernel config
KERNEL_DEFCONFIG:stm31mp1 = "defconfig"
```

When I bitbake linux-stm32mp successfully, I found that the content of the patch is not applied.

Patch file link: [0001-Stargazer-OS-Kernel-Enablement.patch](https://pastebin.com/5HTMs0nw)

My doubts here:

1. I only add one line of code at `init/main.c`

   ```
   pr_notice("Stargazer OS Kernel development enablement\n");
   ```

   on top of

   ```
   pr_notice("Kernel command line: %s\n", saved_command_line);
   ```

   in function

   ```
   asmlinkage __visible void __init __no_sanitize_address start_kernel(void)
   ```

   Why the patch file showing entire content of `init/main.c`? As I have previous build and boot this in my stm32mp1 board, I expect have one line different.
2. Why is the patch not applied at all, and why no error was thrown during bitbake?

Any advice on debugging this will be helpful.

PS: I am aware of STM32MP1 wiki on modifying kernel but I want to try it on yocto cross compiling to understand the yocto build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will put the commands to create the patch in case you did miss something:

The following commands I used on my custom build with machine (`menzu`).

Follow them carefully and compare them to yours.

**File Modification**

```
cd tmp/work-shared/menzu/kernel-source
```

Modify `init/main.c` and check the difference:

```
git status
```

Output:

```
modified:   init/main.c
```

Check the difference:

```
git diff init/main.c
```

Output:

```
diff --git a/init/main.c b/init/main.c
index c0206c507..57531a4a2 100644
--- a/init/main.c
+++ b/init/main.c
@@ -605,6 +605,7 @@ asmlinkage __visible void __init start_kernel(void)
        build_all_zonelists(NULL);
        page_alloc_init();
 
+       pr_notice("Stargazer OS Kernel development enablement\n");
        pr_notice("Kernel command line: %s\n", boot_command_line);
        /* parameters may set static keys */
        jump_label_init();
(END)
```

**Patch Creation**

Format the patch:

```
git add init/main.c
git commit -m "Update init main.c"
git format-patch -1 -o /home/talel/Documents/FinalGit/Authento/meta-authento/recipes-kernel/linux/files/
```

File is created as:

```
/home/talel/Documents/FinalGit/Authento/meta-authento/recipes-kernel/linux/files/0001-Update-init-main.c.patch
```

Add file to `.bbappend`:

```
SRC_URI_append = " file://0001-Update-init-main.c.patch"
```

**Tasks**

Manually unpack and check `${WORKDIR}`:

```
bitbake linux-menzu -c unpack
```

Get `${WORKDIR}`

```
bitbake -e linux-menzu | grep ^WORKDIR=
```

The patch is unpacked correctly under `${WORKDIR}`.

Check if `init/main.c` does not have the modification `${WORKDIR}/git/init/main.c`

Run the patch:

```
bitbake linux-menzu -c patch
```

Check `init/main.c` again, and it should have the new modification.

**NOTE**

- `${WORKDIR}/git` is a symbolic link to `tmp/work-shared/menzu/kernel-source`.
- Only add the `init/main.c` file with `git` command to format the patch.

Comment: I completely agree your answer should be the best known method for most of the yocto out there, but not for stm32mp1 yocto, i cannot explain why, event stm32mp1 wiki kernel patching method was not using the best known method you mentioned. I will raise this question in ST community soon.

Answer (score 0):

Talel BELHADJSALEM answer should be the best known solution for most of the yocto patching, however it not working for stm32mp1.
My work around for this,

1. check the kernel recipe, identify the the kernel repo from the recipe
2. clone the mentioned repo manually in the host.
3. create a patch from it and place it at bbappend file.
4. build and boot the image

   root@stm32mp1:~# dmesg | grep Star

   [    0.000000] Stargazer OS Kernel development enablement

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem in the suffix `stm31mp1` of `KERNEL_DEFCONFIG`?

```
#Appply default kernel config
KERNEL_DEFCONFIG:stm31mp1 = "defconfig"
```

I believe it should be `stm32mp1`.